# Stolen crypto by https://launch-gaimin.io/

Tags: scam

The following Hash were scams, 10000 agi and 3000 arkm stolen via website https://launch-gaimin.io/

0x7cbce79a94830b207b9e8eb76fde81224b5c839c578c3323ce38bd7ae5c4f2a5
0x6863960136917326d67fc7ff4bdf403d1efbe09b1c953671ebbd0478cb73ff63

https://etherscan.io/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789
https://etherscan.io/address/0x6e2a43be0b1d33b726f0ca3b8de60b3482b8b050

May there be anything that could be done?  It appears that my tokens are still being held in above address, could it be recovered?

I am very sorry for being so stupid and dumb.